# How to pass arguments to custom repositories in Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, silex

I've defined my entity using YAML driver:

```
My\Entity\Section:
    type: entity
    table: section
    repositoryClass: My\Entity\SectionRepository
```

As you can see I've specified a **custom repository class**. I'm using the result cache and I'd like to have full control over the cache TTL, i.e. share the `$frontCacheTtl` parameter among different repository.

Here is an example repository, but I really don't know **how to pass parameters to the constructor** when getting the repository through `$entityManager->getRepository('My\Entity\Section')`:

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class SectionRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function __construct($frontCacheTtl)
    {
        $this->frontCacheTtl = $frontCacheTtl;
    }

    public function findAllForFront()
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->select(array('s.slug', 's.title', 's.meta_description'))
            -getQuery();

        $query->useResultCache(true);
        $query->setResultCacheLifetime($this->frontCacheTtl);

        return $query->getArrayResult();
    }
}
```

I'm using SIlex if it matters.

**EDIT**: one solution (but i don't like it...) would be:

```php
$app['repository.factory'] = $app->protect(function ($entityClass) use ($app) {
    // The entity manager (using DoctrinOrmServiceProvider)
    $repository = $app['orm.em']->getRepository($entityClass);

    // Call setters i.e. dependency injection
    $repository->setFrontCacheTtl($app['front_cache_ttl']);

    return $repository;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with the answer provided by **user1191081** which works fine with Symfony, the same for Silex would be:

```
$app['images_repository'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    // The entity manager (using DoctrinOrmServiceProvider)
    $repository = $app['orm.em']->getRepository('\App\Entity\Image');

    // Call setters i.e. dependency injection
    $repository->setFrontCacheTtl($app['front_cache_ttl']);

    return $repository;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You haveto register your custome repository as service, you can pass arguments to service

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container